# Are angled Borders for a UIView possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-graphics

I want to have a angled Borders for my UIView. I know i can create round borders with:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Is it possible? Answers in Swift or Objective C are welcome.

I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Simply override drawRect and draw the view the way you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `CAShapeLayer` with the path you'd like your border to have as a sublayer of `view.layer` to have more freedom in how the border is drawn.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that